# ''Wassup, can a loc come up in your crib''?

Tags: slang

I think, in the first mission of Franklin in the video-game GTA 5, Llamar says this to Franklin in front of a house:

> Wassup, can a loc come up in your crib?

What does that mean? I just can't even guess it's meaning.
For more context:
Franklin responds with:

> Man f*** you, I'll see you at work.

And here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXZtVoQ0gqs)

Comment: Hey (What's up?), can a local guy (me) visit your place (crib)? Can I come in?

Comment: It's very limited currency ***gangland slang*** in California. ***Loc = loco = crazy*** somehow morphed into being a generalised term for Hispanic members of certain street gangs. I think in context here it's the Latino equivalent of ***blood*** or ***homie*** as used by ***negro*** gang members (or plain ***guy*** as used by more mainstream speakers).

Comment: Try the Urban Dictionary for loc, number 5. crib=apartment. Wassup, what's up.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm pretty sure it's from ***loco***, not ***location***

Comment: @jsw29: I actually thought I'd closevoted immediately before posting that comment (I didn't know the usage until I googled ***slang loc***, but it was easy to pick out a link to Urban Dictionary from that search). But apparently I ***didn't*** closevote, so I've duly posted it as an answer now. I still don't think it's a very good question for ELU, though. And I'm not too keen on the idea that a computer gaming company seems to be promoting a usage that's apparently derived from criminally insane gangbang rapists, anyway.

Comment: dayum. who knew this meme would take over the world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very limited currency "gangland slang" in California.

[***Loc = loco = crazy***](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Loc) somehow morphed into being a generalised term for Hispanic members of certain street gangs (you can read all about it in that link; I can't be bothered). I think in context here it's the Latino equivalent of ***blood*** or ***homie*** as used by negro gang members (or plain ***dude, guy*** as used by more mainstream speakers).

Comment: What does "limited currency" mean in the context of your answer?

Comment: [**Currency**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/currency) - *The fact or quality of being **generally accepted** or **in use**.* ***Limited*** currency because outside of "Hispanic members of certain street gangs", not many people would even *understand* the usage, let alone be likely to actually *use* anything like that themselves.